# Is the movement of heated gas via combustion considered "work" and thus a form of mechanical energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

I'm teaching middle school kids about energy, but I got curious for my own education:

Does heated gas, as a product of combustion, produce mechanical energy or is this conversion (from chemical to mechanical) too negligible to consider as a significant form of mechanical energy? (Maybe due to the negligible mass of the gas products $\frac12mv^2$)

If not, is there a scenario where the combustion in a system can be altered in such a way where mechanical work is done by the gas?

Comment: Are you familiar with how an internal combustion engine (car engine) works?

Comment: Yes. It uses the Otto cycle right? I should have been more specific; does open flames convert a significant amount of chemical energy into mechanical energy, and if so under what conditions? Or is a combustion engine the only way to do such a conversion? I believe hot air balloons use open flames take advantage of differences in pressure, to convert heat into mechanical energy.

Comment: The hot air balloon does work to expand against the atmosphere.  But this is similar to what happens in an internal combustion engine; but, in an engine, it can be repeated many cycles and with a balloon, it's a one shot deal.

Comment: I guess the only way this conversion can happen the way I imagine would through be an explosion? Where the gas moves rapidly enough to where there is mechanical energy being done, but this technically wouldn't count as combustion I'm assuming?

Comment: When you have chemical reactions like that which can be used to produce mechanical work, the reaction causes an increase in both the temperature of the reaction mixture and its volume (by producing more moles of gaseous products than that of the reactants you started with).  That's what also produces the pressure which, when combined with the volume increase, translates into work.

Answer (score 1):

It is chemical energy, and it can be transformed into heat and from here to work, like in an Otto engine. Here the efficiency is limited by the Carnot efficiency. Alternatively,  it can be transformed directly into work, like in molecular engines, or fuel cells, which in general are more efficient. I might be wrong on this, but I do not think there is a equivalent to a Carnot cycle that can limit the efficiency of chemical energy conversion into work. It can be theoretically close to 100% according to [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=ztJ2tdO3YlAC&pg=SL5-PA213&dq=carnot%27s#v=onepage&q=carnot's&f=false) source

Answer (score 0):

If the combustion takes place in a rigid chamber not allowing expansion  no work can be done and you simply have a conversion of internal chemical potential energy to internal kinetic energy raising the temperature and pressure of the gas. If it takes place in a cylinder fitted with a movable piston allowing the gas to expand against the piston, the gas can do work. As pointed out, this is what happens in an internal combustion engine.

Hope this helps

Comment: Would a hot air balloon be considered a more indirect conversion from chemical energy into mechanical energy? (chemical-> internal kinetic->mechanical)? I guess this would only be mechanical energy by virtue of the load attached to the balloon and not by the gas itself.

Comment: The combustion causes the air in the balloon to heat up and become less dense than the air outside the balloon. The difference in density causes an upward mechanical buoyant force raising the balloon and the load doing work on the load increasing its gravitational potential energy. Hope this helps.